# How to transfer to unix variable

Tags: variables, unix, sqlplus

I have written a script so that i can read from an oracle database and display it once i run the script. Is there any way that I can transfer the result to unix variable?

```
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s /nolog<<EOF
connect useid/password@CFQ143
set pages 0 feed off
select count (platform) from platformspecific where platform='EF';
exit
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer - rather than use single quotes to pass the value to a variable, you can use open and close brackets to transfer the values:

```
var=$($ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s /nolog<<EOF
connect useid/password@CFQ143
set pages 0 feed off
select count (platform) from platformspecific where platform='EF';
exit
EOF)

echo $var
```